# Avoid duplicate data from second row while using multiple joins?

Tags: sql-server

I am using a join query as mentioned below,

```
select rlld.lead_id,rlcm.Client_id,rlcd.CONTACT_ID,gpew.GP_EW_ID
       ,gpew.CURRENT_TYPE,gpew.CURRENT_GP_JAN 
from dbo.RS_LMS_LEAD_DETAILS rlld  
join dbo.RS_LMS_CLIENT_MASTER rlcm on rlld.CLIENT=rlcm.CLIENT_ID 
left join dbo.RS_LMS_CLIENT_CONTACT_DETAILS rlcd on rlcm.CLIENT_ID=rlcd.CLIENT_ID 
left join dbo.RS_LMS_CURRENT_GP_EW gpew on rlld.LEAD_ID=gpew.LEAD_ID 
where rlld.lead_id='SPE17051734'
```

The data what I am getting and what I am expecting is attached as an image,
Basically any column should not repeat from second row instead it should set it as null or empty.

[image: Remove duplicates from each row and column, It is ok even if it null or empty]

Comment: Do this in your application code. SQL is not the suitable tool for such manipulation

Answer (score 1):

```
select  lead_id     = case when row_number() over (partition by rlld.lead_id order by rlcm.Client_id, rlcd.CONTACT_ID, gpew.GP_EW_ID) = 1 then rlld.lead_id end
       ,Client_id   = case when row_number() over (partition by rlld.lead_id, rlcm.Client_id order by rlcd.CONTACT_ID, gpew.GP_EW_ID) = 1 then rlcm.Client_id end
       ,CONTACT_ID  = case when row_number() over (partition by rlld.lead_id, rlcm.Client_id, rlcd.CONTACT_ID order by gpew.GP_EW_ID) = 1 then rlcd.CONTACT_ID end 
       ,gpew.GP_EW_ID
       ,gpew.CURRENT_TYPE,gpew.CURRENT_GP_JAN 
from dbo.RS_LMS_LEAD_DETAILS rlld  
join dbo.RS_LMS_CLIENT_MASTER rlcm on rlld.CLIENT=rlcm.CLIENT_ID 
left join dbo.RS_LMS_CLIENT_CONTACT_DETAILS rlcd on rlcm.CLIENT_ID=rlcd.CLIENT_ID 
left join dbo.RS_LMS_CURRENT_GP_EW gpew on rlld.LEAD_ID=gpew.LEAD_ID 
where rlld.lead_id='SPE17051734'
```